# It it safe to remove an unused bone?

Tags: bones, vertex-groups

I'm making a shirt for Sims 4 and couldn't find a Sims 4 reference mesh shaped like mine from which to transfer the weight paint. I ended up using a full body mesh, but now I have vertex groups for calves and feet. I don't know if it's okay to leave them there or not. Should I remove them? Is it safe to do so? And would just deleting these vertex groups be enough or do I need to do more? Thank you!

Comment: Just make sure nothing you have requires those vertex groups (such as bones or particle systems).  If nothing is using it, and you have no further use of them, the go right on ahead!  However, you don't have to delete them; you could just not use them.  Whichever you want.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can remove groups and keep the bone.  That won't hurt the bone, it will just mean that the bone no longer influences that part of the mesh.  PS: if anyone has a problem with me posting this as a comment instead of an answer, I'll change it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought using a full body outfit would make no difference since my mesh is just a shirt and wouldn't use the calf and foot bones. But someone said that transferring weights from a full body mesh to a shirt is bad practice. I'm learning still so am always worried I'm going to mess something up. :)